# My minimap is not working and my pausemenu is not loading

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

My minimap is not working and my pausemenu is not loading. I changed XML but still my pausemenu is not working. I searched the minimap problem, it said

> Settings, click Display, and check if Radar is set to on. If it isn't, then set it to on.

I tried it but it did not work.